# how remove invalid token in R.java in android

Tags: android

public static final int 61=0x7f020004;

I m creating one XML file than after few time xml is removed from layout file but the id of that xml is as it is in to the R.java file and it displays error like Invalid token in id R.java file.i already clean and restart eclipse but the R.java file still display an error. what can i do please help me.

Comment: Chances are you have at least 1 xml file that contains error.

Comment: you have something stupid like `android:id="@+id/61"` in your xml ....

Comment: i already delete the xml file.

Comment: Check all your xml files to make sure there is no error, and build again.

Answer (score 0):

You should Build Clean your project, so Eclipse will delete all old references.

Answer (score 0):

And when the problem is not solved delete the R.java
 and clean and build the project

Comment: when i delete the R.java file than immidiately recreate with the previous error..

Comment: Delete bin folder and try again